# Why is there a capacitor power-to-ground on a PWM circuit

Tags: pwm, motor-controller

[image]

I'm using PWM for a motor speed control.

The circuit was purchased and the DC motor scrounged.  The circuit is rated for 20A. I can't be sure what it's drawing because I have no spec or nameplate on the motor.  Supply is a 12V battery.

I understand how [basic PWM works as in this circuit.](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/pulse-width-modulation.html)

[image]

The unit I'm using has an additional capacitor (actually 2 in parallel) like [C1 in this circuit.](https://www.circuitbasics.com/pulse-width-modulation/)

[image]

The reason I'm posting the question is that the capacitors smoked the second time I used it.  It still ran the motor, but only at full speed.  Adjusting the variable resistor had no effect.

I haven't traced the whole circuit to confirm that it matches the link above. I am sure that the blown capacitors go from power to ground.  They are 47uF, 250V running on a 12V supply.

- What do the capacitors do?
- Why can I run the circuit without them?
- What happened to my speed control?

[image: Motor controller board]

Comment: The caps are 470uF 63V, not 47uF 250V. One possibility is that the ripple current was too high and they dissipated too much power.

Comment: What do I do about it?

Comment: If the battery ripple voltage was too high then the cap ripple current may exceed thermal limits  . Analyze that! Using ESR of each part.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a link for the purchased PWM speed control? The 47 uF 250 VDC capacitors do not seem to be appropriate for a controller that will work on a 12 VDC supply and provide 20 amps. I don't see any reason why the capacitors would be destroyed when supplied with 12 VDC (unless polarity was reversed), but more likely the circuit is not designed for the low voltage and high current, and one of the high side transistors shorted out.

If you can, please post some images of the controller and your set-up.

To answer your question about why such capacitors are used on the supply, they are there to provide a low impedance path for current surges through the controller into the motor. This is especially important if the connections to the voltage source (battery) are long and have high resistance and/or inductance.

Comment: Link to the speed control: https://store.qkits.com/electronics/dc-motor-speed-control/20-amp-pwm-for-led-strip-dimming-or-small-motor-control-or-hydrogen-fuel-cell-regulation-7-24-vdc.html.  I said 250V, apparently that should be 63V. 
I'm new to the forum; how do I post pictures?

Comment: Ok, found how to post pictures. 
The transistors look fine.

Comment: If the motor runs, but the speed control does not work, it is very likely that one or more of the power transistors are shorted, or possibly the controller IC is damaged. The transistors can be tested to some extent with a multimeter. One possibility is that there were high voltage inductive spikes from the DC motor during PWM switching, and if there was no effective commutating diode, that inductive energy could cause component failure. It's also possible that this spike could have caused a high energy transient into the supply capacitors causing a short circuit and destruction.

Comment: More likely the capacitors failed through heat and age. Then without decoupling, the diode simply places high voltage spikes on the 12V rail instead of limiting them to 12V, possibly destroying transistors etc.